# spiltting an array into n arrays and accessing individual arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of 1000 emails.

And I want to split the array into n arrays having 45 emails in each array.

I want to separately access the splitted arrays.

How can we implement using php. I have also tried `array_splice()` function in php, but it returns splitted arrays, but I unable to access the splitted array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) in this case to get batches of those emails:

```
$emails = array('email1', 'email2', ..... 'email1000');

// 45 each batch
$batch_emails = array_chunk($emails, 45);

foreach($batch_emails as $batch) {
    print_r($batch);
}

// or explicitly get batch/group 5
print_r($batch_emails[4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
$f = array_chunk($yourArray, 45);
var_dump($f);
```

`Chunks an array into arrays with size elements. The last chunk may contain less than size elements.`